# Advanced Custom Fields Wordpress Repeater Field Order By Date

Tags: php, wordpress, date, advanced-custom-fields

I am using advanced custom fields pro to store and display information on estate sale dates. These are held in a repeater field, each row in the field has a start time, end time and a date. I need to display the information ordered by the date in the repeater field row. Currently it is ordered by date modified. I have tried several solutions but none seem to work for what I need to do.

This is what I have currently:

```
<?php
$latestes = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'estate-sales',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'orderby' => 'modified',
        'order' => 'DESC'
        )
    );

while ( $latestes->have_posts() ) : $latestes->the_post();
    echo '<li class="frontpage-esale"><a href="';
    the_permalink();
    echo '">';
    the_title();
    echo '&nbsp;';
    $rowses = get_field('estate_sale_dates');
    $first_row = $rowses[0];
    $first_row_date = $first_row['es-date'];
    $first_row_start = $first_row['es-start-time'];
    $first_row_end = $first_row['es-end-time'];
    echo '&nbsp;-&nbsp;';
    if ($first_row_date) {
        echo date('F j, Y',strtotime($first_row_date));
    }
    else {
    echo 'Sale Dates TBA';
    }
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

The most common answer when searching for a solution is to do something like this:

```
$latestes = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'estate-sales',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'orderby' => 'modified',
        'order' => 'DESC'
        )
    );

while ( $latestes->have_posts() ) : $latestes->the_post();
$repeater = get_field('estate_sale_dates');
    foreach( $repeater as $key => $row )
    {
        $column_id[ $key ] = $row['es-date'];
    }
    array_multisort( $column_id, SORT_ASC, $repeater );
    foreach( $repeater as $row ) {
    echo '<li class="frontpage-esale"><a href="';
    the_permalink();
    echo '">';
    the_title();
    echo '&nbsp;';
    $rowses = get_field('estate_sale_dates');
    $first_row = $rowses[0];
    $first_row_date = $first_row['es-date'];
    $first_row_start = $first_row['es-start-time'];
    $first_row_end = $first_row['es-end-time'];
    echo '&nbsp;-&nbsp;';
    if ($first_row_date) {
        echo date('F j, Y',strtotime($first_row_date));
    }
    else {
    echo 'Sale Dates TBA';
    }
    }
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

However, when I try that, it lists each sale 3 times, does not order by the date at all, and if no date is entered (which needs to just default to Sale Dates TBA) it throws an error.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any reason why you're passing `'orderby' => 'modified', order=> 'DESC'`?

Comment: Just general format to crank up the WP_Query and pull all posts.

Comment: Due to it being a sub field in a repeater field, it does not work trying to sort by $key and meta numerical order inside the WP_Query array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, that your integration isn't complete, signaled by having two `get_field('estate_sale_dates');`, and the name `$first_row` being out of place when iterating all of them. Without the sort, you're basically doing

```
  $repeater = get_field( 'estate_sale_dates' );
  ...
  foreach ( $repeater => $row_that_isnt_used )
  {
     $rowses = get_field( 'estate_sale_dates' );
     $first_row = $rowses[0]; 
  }
```

I think something like this is what you're after:

```
<?php
while ( $latestes->have_posts() ) {
                $latestes->the_post();
    echo '<li class="frontpage-esale"><a href="';
    the_permalink();
    echo '">';
    the_title();
    echo '</a> ';

    if ( ! count( $sale_dates = get_field('estate_sale_dates') ) )
        echo '<span>Sale Dates TBA</span>';
    else
    {
        // $order = array_column( $sale_dates, 'es-date' ): (php 5.5+)
        foreach( $sale_dates as $ignore => $row )
            $order[] = $row['es-date'];

        array_multisort( $order, SORT_ASC, $sale_dates );

        echo "<ul>";
        foreach( $sale_dates as $row ) {
            $date  = $row['es-date'];
            $start = $row['es-start-time'];
            $end   = $row['es-end-time'];
            echo "<li>" . date('F j, Y',strtotime($row_date)) . " $start-$end</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }

    echo "</li>";
}
```

Comment: Trying this I just get tons of errors, operators not supported, etc.

Comment: Typos were not the issue, I had fixed those, no big deal on typos. But I get this Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings. Associated with $order[] = $row['es-date']

Comment: I think maybe a point is being missunderstood. I need the order of each estate sale to come out based on their sale date "es-date". Each estate sale is a custom post type, es-date is a sub field of estate_sale_dates repeater field.

Comment: Aha, that wasn't clear, thanks. Well, then you can't use 'the loop' that way, you'll need to sort it before that. I think you're then looking for [order posts by custom fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/orde-posts-by-custom-fields/)?

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem with a calendar. There is no solution to do this in the right way with a repater field. The best way to do this, is to use an custom field in an hidden post type and a relation field.

Because any PHP solution is inperformant.

Make a Custom Post Type "Sales Dates" an in this a custom field "date" and a second "Post Relation".
Then select from Post Type "Sales Dates" all Posts order by meta key "dates" with the relation field you get the data from the not hidden post type.

Comment: A custom post type with an ACF field for date will work. I have it running on a client site.

Comment: But an ACF field for Date within ACF Repeater Fied will not work for sorting. In the best case it works inperformant. There is a diffrence between.

Comment: All you do is sort by meta key. It's not hard. Example: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/orde-posts-by-custom-fields/. As a custom post type - no issue. As a repeater - doesn't work.

Comment: You are wrong! This is only possible, if you have an ACF Date Field. If Your ACF Date Field is in an ACF Repeater Field, when this isn't possibe.

Comment: For example: a tour from an artist with many dates and locations. The dates and locations are stored in an ACF Repeater Field. You will show all the Dates in an calendar. This isn't possible. And if you have many artists with many tours with many dates and you will order it in a list, when you need two post types with ACF Relation Fields. If you store the dates in a ACF Repeater Field you can't sort it without performance loss.